# Alexa intent triggered but the reply is "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am using city slots. So, now what i am trying to do is to get alexa speak the city name.But it isn't working.

```
const GetCityNameIntent = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GetCityNameIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const cityName = this.event.request.intent.slots.City.value;
        const speakOutput = `${cityName} is this` ;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the slot value by using the following code.

```
Alexa.getSlotValue(SlotName)
```

Or if you want to go in a standard way you can do the following.

```
handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.SlotName.value
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the slot value:

```
const cityName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.cityName.value;
```

I assume your slotName is cityName here.

```
const speakOutput = cityName + ' is here';
```